# How do you determine which ethernet standard I am using?

Tags: ethernet, wiring

I am new to the field and learning as a gateway via Ethernet cabling.  I was curious as to how exactly these standards were implemented.

Are these standards implemented as per the data transfer rates your ISP sets for you (i.e. the ISP itself is conforming to said standards)?

Is this dependent on something on the user end?

As an additional part to this question, though kind of unrelated..I was wondering if there were any cheap copper whole sources that are already gauged for home applications?  Sources for insulation, etc?

I want to try to do this project hands-on rather than crimping pre-existing lengths of CAT-x cables.  Though, I may do a small project on some extra CAT-5 cable I have laying around as to practice.

EDIT:  If this is the wrong forum for the first question, my apologies.  That said, I forgot about determining my NIC, which I have done..fairly standard issue, but there is nothing I have seen indicating as to which standard it implements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standards for modern wired ethernet are defined in 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX and 1000BASE-T [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair).  These are defined in various IEEE standards in the 802.3 series.

Twisted-pair Ethernet is point-to-point.  Bigger networks are built up using switches and routers.  As such, the devices on each end of *each* link negotiate between themselves what is the fastest speed they both support - typically 10, 100 or 1000Mbps.  It's quite possible to have a network where different devices are talking at different speeds.

This speed is totally unrelated to your ISP's broadband speed, which is probably not delivered over Ethernet anyway.

I can't imagine that building your own CAT-5 Ethernet cable is going to be easy.  The standards are quite strict.  Through something approximating to the standard may work over short distances.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification..will get back to you when I eventually do that project to show you the results, if interested.  Thanks again

Comment: Making custom Cat5 cables isn't that bad, I do it all the time at work with nothing but a $10 eBay crimper. Ethernet is pretty forgiving, it has to be, several hundred meters of cabling and high speeds don't go together unless you've got some good signal path compensation built in, a couple extra bodged plugs isn't going to add much more of a discontinuity.